# Within fakeroot, why does chown return EPERM even though it succeeds (but then again it didn't)?

Tags: linux, chown, fakeroot

I've been running into bizarre behavior when using [chown(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chown) within a fakeroot environment.
The following minimal program illustrates the issue:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {
    //choose a reasonably unique filename
    char path[30];
    sprintf(path, "./file-%d", getpid());

    //create file
    close(creat(path, 0644));

    //chown to some random UID/GID
    chown(path, 4444, 4444);

    //stat again (result can be seen in strace below)
    struct stat s;
    stat(path, &s);

    return 0;
}
```

Suppose that is `main.c`. Now I run the following within a `fakeroot bash`:

```
$ gcc -o main main.c
$ strace -v ./main
...
creat("./file-10872", 0644)             = 3
close(3)                                = 0
...
lchown("./file-10872", 84, 84)          = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
stat("./file-10872", {st_dev=makedev(8, 3), st_ino=3932971, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1001, st_gid=100, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=0, st_size=0, st_atime=2015/10/31-20:12:07, st_mtime=2015/10/31-20:12:07, st_ctime=2015/10/31-20:12:07}) = 0
...
$ ls -l file-10872
-rw-r--r-- 1 4444 4444 0 31. Okt 20:12 file-10872
```

What can we see here?

1. The `chown` call failed with EPERM (Operation Not Permitted).
2. The subsequent `stat` shows `st_uid=1001, st_gid=100` which is my real (non-fake) UID and GID (which is weird because, if I understand fakeroot correctly, it should at least show `st_uid=0, st_gid=0`).
3. The subsequent `ls -l` on the same file shows that the `chown` SUCCEEDED even though `chown` reported failure and the subsequent `stat` confirmed that.

What the heck is going on here? Have I found a bug in fakeroot, or is this just a misunderstanding of how fakeroot works?

(My `fakeroot` is version 1.20.2, and my system is Arch Linux with all updates.)

**Update:** It has been correctly pointed out by Jonas Wielicki that strace works on the syscall level and thus is misleading since the results of the syscalls will be mangled by libfakeroot before being returned to the program itself. It turns out that after `stat(path, &s)`, the `struct stat s` contains the new UID and GID. But it's still confusing that `chown` fails with EPERM.

Comment: That ``strace`` shows incorrect values is not that surprising, I would in fact expect it to see what the system actually returns, not what fakeroot layers above that; same for the error values. Printing the uid and gid from the main.c shows the correct (faked, that is = 4444) values. However, adding perror() and printf(… errno) calls to your code shows that the errors propagate outside of the chown(2) call in the C code. Oddly enough, with a small python (3.4) test, I am not getting exceptions and the values returned are as expected. Without fakeroot, the python script throws PermissionError.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chown` in fact returns zero when run under `fakeroot`. Thus, according to `errno(3)`:

> Its  value is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., -1 from most system calls; -1 or NULL  from  most library functions); a function that succeeds is allowed to change errno.

The value in `errno` is not significant and `chown` did in fact not fail.

As already discussed in the comments, the `strace` output contains EPERM and non-faked uids/gids as expected, as `strace` traces below the fakeroot `LD_PRELOAD` library. Printing the uid/gid from the program shows the correct (faked) output.